# How can I set a queue status for Twilio SMS messages via PHP?

Tags: php, sms, queue, twilio

I've integrated Twilio for a client, but I need to incorporate their hours of operation. I know the sms messages have statuses, but how can I control the status when the message is created? I need the message to be created, but IF it's outside of hours of operation to NOT send the text... so put it in a queue... then when hours open again, send the text.

I see how I can query a sent message and see the status... but I want to specify the status and make sure it doesn't get sent until I specify when.

Please let me know how I can accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio.

This is something you'll have to build into your application logic.

There are plenty of approaches you could take here such as scheduling a cron job or using a worker like Iron.io [as seen in this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/08/build-a-scheduled-reminder-app-with-twilio-and-ironworker.html).

I hope this info helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but did you down-vote my question? I Googled half the day today trying to find a way to actually utilize the "queued" status of Twilio messages... to no avail. I did research... but assumed based on those pieces of data that is built in that there must be some way to utilize it. Yes, I could do it externally and figured I'd have to, but was seeing if there was a better option that I was unable to find. I'll check out your link, but just build it outside of Twilio completely I imagine. :/

Comment: I did not down vote your question @N8Dog. Unfortunately, the `queued` status parameter of Twilio does not work like you were hoping. I understand your frustration, I'm sorry.